# error when trying to execute to sql

Tags: postgresql, log4j, mule, mule-studio

I'm using Mulestudio and am trying to insert into the Postgres database some data. I am modifying the log4j.properties file and below is how it looks like:

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, postgres
#
log4j.appender.postgres=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.postgres.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.postgres.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
log4j.appender.postgres.URL=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/testing
log4j.appender.postgres.user=postgres
log4j.appender.postgres.password=pw
log4j.appender.postgres.sql=INSERT INTO LOGS VALUES ('%x', '%d{yyyy-MM-dd}','%C','%p','%m');
```

The error message that I get is

```
log4j:ERROR Failed to excute sql
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "edu"
```

'edu' is the first part of my project name (edu-stream-ucdnews). The instance of 'edu' only comes up in the title name and not in my data. I know that the error arises when I have the '%m' when I try to insert the data because when I change it to a hard-coded message like 'Hello', I don't get any error.

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your are connected to the database?

Try putting the fields name in your sql and lets check if we get a better error log:

```
log4j.appender.postgres.sql=INSERT INTO LOGS (field1, field2, ...) VALUES ('%x', '%d{yyyy-MM-dd}','%C','%p','%m');
```